# Why isn't my delete button working?

Tags: php, jquery

My code is: (**Edited** after a suggestion from an answer)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SomuFinance - Personal Finance Manager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexStyle.css">
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <div id="container">
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="edit" value="Edit" />
            <input type="button" class="button" name="delete" value="Delete" />
            <input type="text" id="action" name="action">
            <table id="listDB">
                <tr>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Category ID</th>
                    <th>Shop</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Price Based On</th>
                    <th>MRP</th>
                    <th>Seller's Price</th>
                    <th>Last Updated On</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    $dbc =  mysqli_connect('localhost','root','atlantis2016','itemDB')
                                or die("Error Connecting to Database");

                    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                    {
                        echo "Action Set to ".$_POST['action'];
                        if($_POST['action']=='confirmDelete')
                        {
                            echo "Now Deleting!!";
                            foreach ($_POST['selected'] as $delete_id) 
                            {
                                $query = "DELETE FROM grocery WHERE id = $delete_id";
                                mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
                                    or die('Error querying database.');
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM grocery";
                    $result1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1)
                                or die("Error Querying Database");

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
                    {
                        $category = $row['category'];
                        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM grocery WHERE category='$category' ORDER BY item ASC";
                        $result2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2)
                                or die("Error Querying Database");

                        echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td class="catHead" colspan=11>'.$category.'</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                        $catCount=1;

                        while($inRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
                        {
                            $id = $inRow['id'];
                            $shop = $inRow['shop'];
                            $item = $inRow['item'];
                            $qnty = $inRow['quantity'];
                            $unit = $inRow['unit'];
                            $price_based_on = $inRow['price_based_on'];
                            $mrp = $inRow['MRP'];
                            $sellers_price = $inRow['sellers_price'];
                            $last_updated_on = $inRow['last_updated_on'];

                            echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td><input type="checkbox" value="' . $id . '" name="selected[]" /></td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$id.'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$catCount.'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$shop.'</td>';
                                echo '<td class="leftAligned">'.$item.'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$qnty.'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$unit.'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$price_based_on.'</td>';
                                echo '<td class="pri">₹'.$mrp.'</td>';
                                echo '<td class="pri">₹'.$sellers_price.'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$last_updated_on.'</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';

                            $catCount++;
                        }
                    }

                    mysqli_close($dbc);
                ?>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="dialogBG">
            <div id="deleteConfirmDialog" class="dialog">
                <div class="closeDialog"></div>
                <p>Sure you want to delete the selected Data?</p>
                <input type="submit" id="confirmDelete" class="dialogButton" name="edit" value="Delete" />
                <input type="button" class="dialogButton cancelButton" name="delete" value="Cancel" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.button').click(function(){
                if($(this).val()=="Delete")
                {
                    $(".dialogBG").fadeIn(200);
                    $("#deleteConfirmDialog").show(200);
                    $("#action").val('confirmDelete');
                }
                else if($(this).val()=="Edit")
                {

                }
            });

            $('#confirmDelete').click(function(){
                $(".closeDialog").trigger("click");
            });
            $('#cancelDelete').click(function(){

            });
            $(".closeDialog").click(function (e){
                $(this).parent(".dialog").hide('200').parent(".dialogBG").fadeOut('200');
            });
            $(".cancelButton").click(function (e){
                $(this).parent(".dialog").hide('200').parent(".dialogBG").fadeOut('200');
            });
            $("form").submit(function(e){
                alert("Form is being sumbitted!");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the elements for which the checkbox is selected, contained in the php array selected[], to be deleted from the database. Before deletion, I want a confirmation dialog box to open up, which will contain the "submit" button. This will cause the actual deletion. However, for some reason the above code doesn't work. I can't even be sure if the post is being submitted, as the line `echo "Action Set to ".$_POST['action'];` doesn't return any output. Please help.

I believe this entire section of code is not working (from manual testing).

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        echo "PHP Working here!";
        echo "Action Set to ".$_POST['action'];
        if($_POST['action']=='confirmDelete')
        {
            echo "Now Deleting!!";
            foreach ($_POST['selected'] as $delete_id) 
                {
                    $query = "DELETE FROM grocery WHERE id = $delete_id";
                    mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
                        or die('Error querying database.');
                }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put these inputs inside a form and set an action. like below:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" role="form">
    <input></input>
    <input></input>
</form>
```

this will be your code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SomuFinance - Personal Finance Manager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexStyle.css">
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" role="form">
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="edit" value="Edit" />
        <input type="button" class="button" name="delete" value="Delete" />
        <input type="text" id="action" name="action">
        <table id="listDB">
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Category ID</th>
                <th>Shop</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Unit</th>
                <th>Price Based On</th>
                <th>MRP</th>
                <th>Seller's Price</th>
                <th>Last Updated On</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $dbc =  mysqli_connect('localhost','root','atlantis2016','itemDB')
                            or die("Error Connecting to Database");

                if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                    echo "Action Set to ".$_POST['action'];
                    if($_POST['action']=='confirmDelete')
                    {
                        echo "Now Deleting!!";
                        foreach ($_POST['selected'] as $delete_id)
                        {
                            $query = "DELETE FROM grocery WHERE id = $delete_id";
                            mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
                                or die('Error querying database.');
                        }
                    }
                }

                $query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM grocery";
                $result1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1)
                            or die("Error Querying Database");

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
                {
                    $category = $row['category'];
                    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM grocery WHERE category='$category' ORDER BY item ASC";
                    $result2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2)
                            or die("Error Querying Database");

                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td class="catHead" colspan=11>'.$category.'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    $catCount=1;

                    while($inRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
                    {
                        $id = $inRow['id'];
                        $shop = $inRow['shop'];
                        $item = $inRow['item'];
                        $qnty = $inRow['quantity'];
                        $unit = $inRow['unit'];
                        $price_based_on = $inRow['price_based_on'];
                        $mrp = $inRow['MRP'];
                        $sellers_price = $inRow['sellers_price'];
                        $last_updated_on = $inRow['last_updated_on'];

                        echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td><input type="checkbox" value="' . $id . '" name="selected[]" /></td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$id.'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$catCount.'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$shop.'</td>';
                            echo '<td class="leftAligned">'.$item.'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$qnty.'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$unit.'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$price_based_on.'</td>';
                            echo '<td class="pri">₹'.$mrp.'</td>';
                            echo '<td class="pri">₹'.$sellers_price.'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$last_updated_on.'</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';

                        $catCount++;
                    }
                }

                mysqli_close($dbc);
            ?>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.button').click(function(){
                if($(this).val()=="Delete")
                {
                    $(".dialogBG").fadeIn(200);
                    $("#deleteConfirmDialog").show(200);
                    $("#action").val('confirmDelete');
                }
                else if($(this).val()=="Edit")
                {

                }
            });

            $('#confirmDelete').click(function(){
                $(".closeDialog").trigger("click");
            });
            $('#cancelDelete').click(function(){

            });
            $(".closeDialog").click(function (e){
                $(this).parent(".dialog").hide('200').parent(".dialogBG").fadeOut('200');
            });
            $(".cancelButton").click(function (e){
                $(this).parent(".dialog").hide('200').parent(".dialogBG").fadeOut('200');
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div class="dialogBG">
        <div id="deleteConfirmDialog" class="dialog">
            <div class="closeDialog"></div>
            <p>Sure you want to delete the selected Data?</p>
              <input type="submit" id="confirmDelete" class="dialogButton" name="edit" value="Delete" />
              <input type="button" class="dialogButton cancelButton" name="delete" value="Cancel" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did that. Still doesn't work. Any other suggestions/ideas?

Comment: well the code is very long, it'll take some time. I'll try but no promises.

Comment: oh, you have to wrap those input inside this form too

Comment: Done. New code in the question (updated). Still doesn't work. I've narrowed down the problem to the form not being submitted. At least that's the first problem. Any ideas?

Comment: so how are you using last paragraph.I mean the pop-up which confirm if you want to submit or not

Comment: Edited the question. There's my new code. The form is submitting now. But the item isn't getting deleted. I'm using the last paragraph's div as a pop up that confirms the deletion. The delete button in it is what submits the form, and it's what'll cause the actual deletion from the database.

Comment: Narrowed down the problem further. See the last para of the question for the edit.

Comment: I think you need to have a form here too

Comment: with same action as the above one.

Comment: or rather have only one form in the last para with both button of `type="submit"` so when you submit this form. php will take action

Comment: Oh, that's impressive. I really got confused and missed that. thank you by the way

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple. `if(isset($_POST['confirmDelete']))` needs to be there instead of `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` in the problem section in the question as there is no button called "submit" in the entire form.